# Creating nested tables

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

Good day. I'm trying to create nested tables one hundred times. However, my code creates one main table and then inside that, there are 100 separate tables. (Thanks to Sir Sachin for the help) What I need is table within a table. Please help me fix the code.

```
<html>
<head> <title> Hello! </title> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function add() { 
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
    numi.value = num;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value=1 id='theValue' /><div id='" + divIdName + "'></td></tr></table>";
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);
    for(var i=1;i<100;i++) {
        var ni = document.getElementById(divIdName);
        var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
        var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
        numi.value = num;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
        newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        var j=i++;
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='" + j + "' id='theValue' /><div id='" + divIdName + "'></td></tr></table>";
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="add()">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' />

        <div id='myDiv'> </div> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you describe what's not working or give us a JSFiddle of your code so that we can see it for ourselves?

Comment: DOM manipulations are slow. You are better off building this up as a string and inserting it in one go at the end.

Comment: what's the hidden input for? do you need nested hidden inputs? why do they all have the same id?

Comment: @Benmj Instead of creating a table within a table within a table (100x), it creates a main table and then inside that main table, there are 100 separate tables (not nested). I tried JSFiddle but it outputs differently compare to the browser's. :)

Comment: @Pete I used the input tag to change the div id. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it (I have removed the hidden input as it is not needed):  http://jsfiddle.net/rPR9w/1/

```
function add() {
    for (i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        addAnother(i);
    }
}


function addAnother(counter) { 
    var container = document.getElementById('myDiv' + counter);
    container.innerHTML = makeTable(counter + 1);
}

function makeTable(counter) {

    return "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <div id='myDiv" + counter + "'></td></tr></table>";

}
```

Comment: it seems not too bad!